# C# skip all proxy exceptions - time-out

Tags: c#, .net, exception, proxy, skip

Is there any way i can skip/catch all proxy exceptions?
  And also maybe put a time-out so the program wont get stuck in-between

```
webProxy = new WebProxy("" + prox + "");
webProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
wr.Proxy = webProxy;
```

I've added

```
             catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Do nothing or log
                var exceptio = ex.ToString();
                richTextBox1.Text = exceptio;
            }
```

how can i put a time-out on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested you need to enclose the executing code in a `try/catch` block.
You can fiddle around with debugger Exception handling under *Debug/Exceptions...* (in Visual Studio) but regardless, any non-handled exception will always trigger the debugger to break.

```
try
{
    // Do work that might fail
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do nothing or log
    Trace.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

More on debugging and exceptions can be found [here](http://All%20non-handled%20exceptions%20will%20trigger%20the%20debugger%20to%20break.)

Regarding time-out, you put it on the `WebRequest` object, not on the proxy, like so:

```
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://myproxyserver:80/");
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
webRequest.Proxy = webProxy;
webRequest.Timeout = 5000;  // <-- Set time out here, in milliseconds
...
```

Read more on timeout [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Would a try/catch block help with this?

Comment: i just what the program to not care about exceptions, and anything arise.. to just skip it and continue ( i keep getting errors while debugging )